# Can some clamp meters measure voltage through their clamp?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, multimeter

A simple question, is it possible any clamp meters to provide voltage readings when a cable is between their clamp?  I see from specifications for meters that they don't seem to do that and instead provide an amp reading.

I assume this is likely because its not possible via this kind of non contact measurement but can someone confirm?

Comment: no ... the clamp measures current running through the cable .... it has no knowledge of the voltage that is present in the cable

Answer (score 3):

Not with your kit but Fluke has just released a non-contact voltage meter with a U shaped probe (not quite a clamp). It believe it works by capacatively sensing the voltage, where the conductor forms one half, and the user forms the other half of the capacitor by touching a metal plate on the back of the meter. Reviews are mixed. Check it out: [Fluke T6-1000](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/uken/electrical-testers/Electrical-Testers/T6-1000-Electrical-Tester.htm?PID=81966)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The voltage measurement mode on clamp meters uses some conventional banana plug terminals on the meter.

Non-contact voltage detection does exist, though how that works is an answer for a different question. But it can't *measure* the voltage, only detect that it's there. (edit: as pointed out in the comments, there are some devices that can measure voltage without contact. They are very inaccurate, though.)

Comment: Non-contact voltage measurement, not detection, does exist. See Fluke's new product in another answer for an example.

Comment: @replete Hm, I expect it's horribly imprecise though. I'd never heard of that, though, good to know!

Comment: @replete: I tried it, it is horribly inaccurate and basically not usable unless you hold your tongue at precisely the right angle. Felthry: DC detection exists, and most detectors do both, e.g. those that you use to locate wires in a wall often get false positives from static electricty.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Clearly I don't know as much about this stuff as I'd thought! I've modified the answer accordingly, though perhaps I should just end up deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: not possible without modifications.

Not so simple answer:

It is possible to measure voltage by non-contact method measuring via high impedance probe via a  larger coupling capacitance to a single wire but not around both.  This is called a capacitance transformer. Capacitance is due to gap and area of surface between non-contact conductor.

As impedance rises with lower frequency it becomes much harder to measure due to coupling E-field to C to small C probe.

Inductive coupling is used for single wires and both wires for common mode noise to detect current from B field transformed into a voltage with a burden resistor.  The coupling must near ideal to record accurately and often has a lower bandwidth than other methods due to clamp size as defined by probe specs.  There is a wide variation of clamp types.

One example is you can detect partial stray line voltage by touching a 10:1 probe then put other hand finger near insulated line single wire and see voltage rise towards line voltage. This is safe due to insulated wire but finger capacitance can be greater than 20pF 10:1 probe so it rises near line voltage but limiting current ~ 30 uA via 10M probe resistance.

- Then short probe of scope with its ground wire around a small battery wire and now you can detect pulses of short circuit current in probe above say 100k~1MHz and see a glitch where decay time =0.35/f-3dB of this HPF current probe. See what you get and report back.

So voltage is measuring E field with very high impedance and current is measuring B field with current loop into low impedance detecting voltage rise.